# MacOS 14.2 R 4.3.2 javareconf does not work

Tags: r, java-native-interface

I am trying to get R reconfigured for the java 21 jdk on Mac OS 14.2 on an arm64 Macbook Pro.

Installed R from the package for version 4.3.2. I have the jdk-21.jdk package in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/

The SDK_ROOT environment variable = /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk.
The JAVA_HOME environment variable = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home and its include subdirectory has a jni.h file.

Yet when I run `R CMD javareconf -n` I obtain the following error:

```
Java interpreter : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
Java version     : 21.0.1
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jar
 
trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : 
detected JNI linker flags : 
using C compiler: ‘clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.2.sdk’
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang-6.0: warning: optimization flag '-falign-functions=64' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program
 
 
JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

It seems like the lack of JNI cpp and linker flags is likely the issue here, but why aren't these being set properly?